# subquery uses ungrouped column "omt.actualendtime" from outer query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Following is the query

```
SELECT omt.actualendtime::date,
       (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
        FROM (SELECT odt.productshortname,
                     count(odt.*) 
              FROM orderdetail_runtime_tran odt 
              WHERE odt.actualendtime::date = omt.actualendtime::date
                AND odt.stagename = 'Ironing'
              GROUP BY odt.productshortname
             ) t
       ) as item_current_count
From orderdetail_runtime_tran omt
WHERE omt.actualendtime IS NOT NULL AND date_part('year', omt.actualendtime) = '2019'
  AND omt.stagename = 'Ironing'
GROUP BY omt.actualendtime::date;
```

This query is giving error

> subquery uses ungrouped column "omt.actualendtime" from outer query

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55037037/edit)  your question and add some sample data and expected results. There should be a better and simpler way to do what you are ultimately trying to achieve rather than fixing that error.

Comment: I don't think sample data will make a difference, but the table definitions would help.

Comment: Yes, providing both will be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a subquery:

```
SELECT actualenddate,
       (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
        FROM (SELECT odt.productshortname, count(odt.*) 
              FROM orderdetail_runtime_tran odt 
              WHERE odt.actualendtime::date = actualenddate AND
                    odt.stagename = 'Ironing'
              GROUP BY odt.productshortname
             ) t
       ) as item_current_count
FROM (SELECT omt.*,
             omt.actualendtime::date as actualenddate
      FROM orderdetail_runtime_tran omt
      WHERE omt.actualendtime IS NOT NULL AND 
            date_part('year', omt.actualendtime) = '2019' AND
            omt.stagename = 'Ironing'
     ) omt
GROUP BY actualenddate;
```